# Unable to start Opera 12

Tags: windows-7, windows, opera

After installing Opera 16, I could not start Opera 12. 
I get this error:

```
Error initialing Opera: module 11(prefs)
```

I reinstalled Opera 12, but the error appears yet.

Comment: From v12 to v16 there was a massive overhaul in the background of Opera. They changed their engine from Presto to Blink. The way they structure the profile folder changed too. So you cannot install the new Opera at the same folder as your old. (Have you?) However, there is a import option in v16 which should import most of your settings.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Opera` folder solved the issue.

Now I have all missed features of version 16!!